# Add a button to scroll down and disable scroll bar scrolling for that region

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is what I want to achieve exactly.

I have an "HTML Form" with some fields which the user needs to fill out, there are a lot of `input` elements so I need a scroll bar for that. At the end of the form I have a `submit` button, when the user hits submit I want the complete form to scroll up and then a new `div` should show up which has all of the information the user has entered.

I don't want this div to be seen before the user clicks submit i.e the scroll function should only be limited to the "HTML form" and the user should not be able to scroll down to this section (The section should only be visible by clicking on the submit button)

How can I do that using jQuery or any other jQuery library?

Comment: Atleast redirect me the proper resources instead of just giving downvotes!

Comment: You should give us the code you have so far to make it easier to work with

Comment: Use `.hide()` and `.show()` to make the DIV invisible and visible. What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `preventDefault` to stop the form from submitting, find the values of each input, return them in a hidden container then slide back up to view:

JS

```
$("input[type=submit]").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault()

  var input1 = $("#field1").val();
  var input2 = $("#field2").val();
  var input3 = $("#field3").val();
  var input4 = $("#field4").val();
  var input5 = $("#field5").val();
  var input6 = $("#field6").val();

  $(".info").html("field 1: " + input1 + " field 2: " + input2 + " field 3: " + input3 + " field 4: " + input4 + " field 5: " + input5 + " field 6: " + input6).show();
  $("html,body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 });

});
```

HTML

```
<div class="info"></div>
<form>
  <input type="text" id="field1"/>
  <input type="text" id="field2"/>
  <input type="text" id="field3"/>
  <input type="text" id="field4"/>
  <input type="text" id="field5"/>
  <input type="text" id="field6"/>
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/d3s6oezw/)

**UPDATE**

Here is a new fiddle that hides the form after submit, displays the info with a "edit" button and shows the form again to edit:

[**NEW FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/d3s6oezw/1/)

Comment: No! your code adds the results on top..I want to show the results on the same page. but the input form should not be visible at the time!

Comment: @harrythomas so you want to hide the form after you submit it?

Comment: yes exactly..The form should hide while viewing the results..if user wishes to edit the information then again there should be some button which will allow him to edit the information

Comment: Yeah! Works like what I want! Thanks a lot ..I am accepting the answer but please guide me on how can I add nice animation effects to this..Thanks

Comment: @harrythomas no problem, glad to help. I would post a separate question for additional help on this since the original question here has been resolved

Answer (score 0):

Well, to start with something, the jQuery you want to use to scroll up/down and hide/show a div when clicking on the submit button is the following:

### jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(function(){
    $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function(){
      if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname){
        var target = $(this.hash);
        target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
        if(target.length){
          $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: target.offset().top
          }, 1000);
          return false;
        }
      }
    });
  });
  $(".hidden").hide(); // Hide all elements you want to be hidden until you send the form
  $(".submit").click(function(){
    $(".hidden").fadeIn(400); // Show hidden items when click on submit button. You may also use show() function if you don't want it to fade in. Change the 400 for the time you want it to take to fade in (in miliseconds). 400 is default so you may just delete the 400.
  });
});
```

This is the supposed HTML you want to use

### HTML

```
<div class="hidden">
    <!-- The div you want to hide and then put all the sent info to show when click on sent -->
</div>
<div class="scroll-section">
  <form method="post" action="" id="form">
    <!-- Your form here -->
    <a href="#form"><input type="submit" value="Submit info" class="submit"/></a>
  </form>
</div>
```

A recommendation I can give you with CSS if you want to make the hidden div cover everything and be on top is that you set `z-index` to a high value and `position:fixed; height:100%; width:100%;`. I usually set a div like that and add a table in it and set it as wide and tall as the div so that I can style one `td` to look like a div in the center of the screen.

EDIT:

I forgot to explain you the scroll thing, you see that I covered the submit button with an `a` tag that points to an `id="form"`.. basically, the jQuery up there works with any given ID. So just set a link pointing to the ID of the element and there you go.

Also, in **CSS**:

```
.scroll-section {
    overflow-y:scroll;
    height:600px; // Give it a height
}
```